# Finding location of gcc compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just performed a fresh installation of Microsoft Visual Studio Code onto my Windows PC. I put it on a non-C: drive because my C: drive is not very large. I have also installed the C/C++ extension.

Unlike when I installed VSC on my Mac, I'm getting an error when I try to run my CPP programs that says "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath." I also get "cannot open source file [thing like iostream, cmath, etc.]" for each include statement.

I think the issue is that in "C/C++ Configurations" there is no compiler path specified, and I don't know where to tell my computer the compiler is. How can I find this out? I have minimal experience with the command line.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an IDE and not, itself, a compiler. Did you also install GCC itself on Windows?

Comment: You’re gonna have to point it to the msvc.exe and the location of all its include files. I’m sure ms has a guide on this. It would boggle my mind if they don’t. Edit: the title says gcc. Gcc on windows is doable, but is a bit of a trick to do, I’d stick with msvc on windows.

Comment: @Taekahn there are more than a few very good ports of GCC on Windows. I have (and always test with) MSVC, LLVM/Clang, MinGW-w64, and TDM-GCC. Each has its strengths.

Comment: @NathanPierson, I realize VSC isn't itself a compiler. I'm a bit confused because I've done an installation on my Mac Book Pro and after adding the C++ extension, I was ready to go (no compiler pointing necessary). As for gcc vs. other C++ compilers, I'll take whatever works. I don't know/prefer one over the other.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I explicitly said it’s doable. I’ve done it. I wouldn’t recommend it for someone that has no experience around command lines while simultaneously trying to integrate it successfully into an ide that doesn’t auto detect/help. It’s just leading them down a path of pain for no good reason imo, when they could just use the easy, native alternative if they want to compile on a windows machine.

Comment: @Taekahn Perhaps. I have found that, speaking for myself, MSVC was trickier to install than the other three I listed, but only because MSVS’s installer needs you to be aware enough to click the proper C++ buttons as you go. Unfortunately, I have yet to play with VSCode, so I’m useless in helping OP answer this question, lol.

Comment: @UniqueWorldline https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc they also have a gcc install version via mingw https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp. The choice is ultimately yours.

Comment: When you installed the compiler and "put it on a non-C: drive" you would have had to specify where to install it.   The compiler (executable), standard header files, and libraries will be either (it depends on how the installation works) in that directory, or in some sub-directory (e.g named `bin` for executuables, `include` for header files, `lib` for libraries).   If you look in that folder structure there may be information (possibly in a bat file under windows) relevant to setting needed environment variables and the path.

Comment: I followed the 1st link @Taekahn posted and installed the cl compiler. The include statements are no longer giving the same error, but when I try to run my code, it says " 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." It seems VSC is looking for the wrong compiler. This is despite me specifying the compiler path in the C/C++ Configurations Page.